# google maps : put markers all over visible section on Google map display

Tags: google-maps

I want to show limited numbers of markers(let's take 50 or so...) at all zoom level and in a manner that markers covers all entire Google map display.

So, If I am viewing whole world in map, it will show markers all over the world not to exceed a certain number, and the if I zoomed to USA  it will only show previous number of markers only inside USA. 
And then again if I moved to Canada , then the map should show markers of Canada only.

**I am not able to 
 - put makers on visible region over the map on limited distances 
 i.e. all the visible markers maintaining somewhat some distance from each other.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into 'clustering' or 'bunching' the points into one. It doesn't do exactly what you are describing, but it will effectively limit the number of markers you have when you are zoomed out, and 'uncluster' them once you zoom in.

There are quite a few ways (all third party - the Google API doesn't support it yet), you could have a look here at one called ClusterMarker: http://googlemapsapi.martinpearman.co.uk/articles.php?cat_id=1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a marker manager!

See http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/ and http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/